# European Numbers RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this `/[-\+,\.0-9]+/` to match numbers in strings like `+4400,00 %` or `-3500,00 %` or `0.00 %`.

The matched results I want is `+4400,00` and I correctly get it.

What if I wanted the same results for a string like `+4.400,00 %` (dot for thousands) ?

**EDIT**

How do I have to modify my RegEx for matching numbers in strings like `<font color="red">+44.500 %</font>`?

Comment: I think there should be a separate StackExchange "Write my regex for me".  Or better yet, a general "Do my work for me".

Comment: Your regex already matches `+4.400,00`. I fail to see the problem. Also, you can write `/[-+,.0-9]+/` with no change in meaning.

Comment: you got reason... sorry :-\ But it was so urgent.... can you point me to a place where I can learn quickly for this specific purpose, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/[\-\+]?\s*[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})*,[0-9]+/
```

That should cover strings that

- may start with a `+` or `-`, and then perhaps some whitespaces
- then have between one and three numbers
- then have groups of three numbers, prefixed with a period
- then have a comma and at least one number behind the comma

---

Regarding your additional question (matching numbers inside strings), you should look into the manual of whatever regex API you're using. Most APIs have separate `search` and `match` methods; `match` wants the whole string to be part of your regular expression's language, while `search` will also match substrings.

Comment: Sorry, can I ask you for this last case: "+ 44.050 %" : the whitespace between the "+" or minus and the number! So what?

Comment: Start with `/[\-\+]?\s*[0-9]` instead. `\s` is usually something like `[ \t\r\n]`, so that matches one whitespace character, so `\s*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

`[\+-]?` - plus or minus

`\d{1,3}` - some digits

`(\.\d{3})*` - groups of 3 digits with point before

`,\d{2}` comma and 2 more digits

And so we get:

`/[+-]?\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*,\d{2}/`

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will already match ".".  But it sounds like you also want to strip "." out?  if that's the case, you need a substiution.  In Perl,

```
if ($input =~ /(-|\+)[0-9][,\.0-9]+/) {
  $input =~ s/\.//;
} else {
  die;
}
```

I've also changed the regex so it will only match - and + at the start, and so it requires an initial digit